# How to bulk open all files with specific name?

Tags: shell, command-line, command

Is there a way to use command line to search all subfolders with a folder (unlimited depth) to find and automatically open every file that's named `footer.php` ?

I was able run

```
find /desktop/themes -name footer.php
```

and it found all of the files but I don't know how to make it open all of them automatically.  Does anyone know how to do this?

(I'm running this in cygwin in case that helps.)

Comment: Well it should open them with the default program which in this case would be NotePad++

Comment: The answer depends on how you would open a single file in the default program from the command line. On Mac OS X, that would be `open footer.php`, so you could use `find $dir -name footer.php -exec open '{}' \;`; I don't know the equivalent to `open` in `cygwin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `gvim -p`. That will open all files in different tabs:

```
find /desktop/themes -name footer.php -print0 | xargs -0 gvim -p
```

Note the use of `-print0` with `xargs -0` for safe parsing of `find`'s output.